# How to disallow empty string when deserializing record types with newtonsoft in F#?

Tags: f#, json.net, json-deserialization

Is there any way to force parsing of only non-empty string fields of a record type in F# using Newtonsoft.Json?

```
#r """Newtonsoft.Json.dll"""

open Newtonsoft.Json

type Customer = {
    Name:           string
    Email:          string
    ContactPhoneNo: string
}

// one or more fields can be empty
let customer = {
    Name =           ""
    Email =          "ca@gmail.com"
    ContactPhoneNo = "+123456789"
}

let serializedCustomer =
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer)

// this parses correctly with the Name field set as ""
// But as the name field is empty, it should not parse it
let deserializedCustomer =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(serializedCustomer)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider using Newtonsoft's schema support for this, which is in a separate package called `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema`. You can specify many different kinds of constraints using annotations. For example, to disallow blank names, you can use `MinLength`:

```ml
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

type Customer = {
    [<MinLength(1)>]
    Name:           string
    Email:          string
    ContactPhoneNo: string
}
```

Once you've annotated your type, you can generate a schema:

```ml
let generator = JSchemaGenerator()
let schema = generator.Generate(typeof<Customer>)
```

Then use it to validate the serialized JSON:

```ml
let jsonCustomer = JObject.Parse(serializedCustomer)
let isValid = jsonCustomer.IsValid(schema)
```

If you want to skip the overhead of first loading JSON into a `JObject` in order to validate it, you can use a `JSchemaValidatingReader` instead:

```ml
use strReader = new System.IO.StringReader(serializedCustomer)
use txtReader = new JsonTextReader(strReader)
use vldReader = new JSchemaValidatingReader(txtReader, Schema = schema)
let messages = ResizeArray()
vldReader.ValidationEventHandler.Add(fun args -> messages.Add(args.Message))
let serializer = JsonSerializer()
let deserializedCustomer = serializer.Deserialize<Customer>(vldReader)
printfn "%A" deserializedCustomer
let isValid = (messages.Count = 0)
printfn "%A" isValid
```

See [this documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/ValidatingJson.htm) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom `JsonConverter` that converts values of type `string`, but throws an exception when the string is empty:

```
let nonEmptyStringConverter = 
  { new JsonConverter() with
      override x.CanConvert(objectType) = objectType = typeof<string>
      override x.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) =
        JValue(value :?> string).WriteTo(writer)
      override x.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer) =
        let jt = JToken.Load(reader)
        if jt.Type = JTokenType.String then 
          let str = jt.Value<string>() 
          if String.IsNullOrEmpty str then failwith "Empty string"
          box str
        else failwith "Expected a string" }
```

If you pass this to `DeserializeObject`, then it will throw an exception in your example:

```
let serializedCustomer =
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer)

let deserializedCustomer =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(serializedCustomer, nonEmptyStringConverter)
```

One caveat is that this will apply to all `string` values in the type and I expect you may want to allow empty values for some. A better approach would be to define a custom type and define a convertor only for this type, e.g. using:

```
type NonEmptyString = NE of string

type Customer = 
  { Name : NonEmptyString
    Email: NonEmptyString
    ContactPhoneNo: string }
```